# AutoCompleteTextView showing duplicates in dropdown for suggestion

Tags: android, duplicates, autocompletetextview

The AutoCompleteTextView is showing duplicates in dropdown for suggestion.

Please tell if anything wrong in my code. Thanks.

```
CustomAutoCompleteTextView email_id; 
email_id = (CustomAutoCompleteTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.etUserId);

// Each row in the list stores  name, email
List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

for (int i = 0; i < jar_contacts.length(); i ++) {
    HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
    hm.put(
       "txt",
       jar_contacts.optJSONObject(i).optString("first_name")
           + " "
           + jar_contacts.optJSONObject(i).optString("surname")
    );
    //hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(flags[i]) );                         

    hm.put(
        "email",
        jar_contacts.optJSONObject(i).optString("user_id_email")
    );
    aList.add(hm);
}

// Keys used in Hashmap
String[] from = { "txt", "email"};

// Ids of views in listview_layout
int[] to = { R.id.tName_auto,R.id.t_email_auto };

// Instantiating an adapter to store each items
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
    ct, aList, R.layout.autocomplete_create_msg, from, to
); 

// Defining an itemclick event listener for the autocompletetextview
OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id {
        /** Each item in the adapter is a HashMap object.
        *  So this statement creates the currently clicked hashmap object
        * */
        HashMap<String, String> hm =
            (HashMap<String, String>) arg0.getAdapter().getItem(position);
    }
};

/** Setting the itemclick event listener */
email_id.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);

/** Setting the adapter to the listView */
email_id.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Where CustomAutoCompleteTextView is a class below which is returning email to be displayed on selection from dropdown.

```
public class CustomAutoCompleteTextView extends AutoCompleteTextView {

    public CustomAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /** Returns the name corresponding to the selected item */
    @Override
    protected CharSequence convertSelectionToString(Object selectedItem) {
        /** Each item in the autocompetetextview suggestion list is a hashmap object */
        HashMap<String, String> hm = (HashMap<String, String>) selectedItem;
        return hm.get("email");
    }
}
```

Comment: `adapter` variable is not defined, with such incomplete code you will receive no answer

Comment: @pskink : i have edited please see

Comment: You should definitely indent your code properly and follow the standard Java coding style. Otherwise nobody can understand your code.

Answer (score 0):

{ email_idsetDuplicateParentStateEnabled(false);
}

Comment: Welcome to SO! Though a good answer is self-explanatory, a short explanation of HOW your answer resolves the problem and what was wrong - is always valuable.